# Protecting user's model view from other users

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to write a generic DetailView for my model (which is related to User), but I don't know how to limit access for specific model (view) for only that User (owner). I've looked into docs but haven't found any guide how to do that the proper way. So far I've managed to overwrite test_func() method of the class using UserPassesTestMixin where i check if `object.user == self.request.user` but I'm not sure if that's the proper way to do that.

What I've just said may not be clear, so e.g.
Model A of id 4 is related (owned by) User A.
Now, if User B tries to request Model A DetailView (/models/4) he should be rejected with 403 Error Code, or even better, custom error page.

Comment: have you read the documentation on authentication yet? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/ The default implementation would be especially useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/

Comment: What is wrong with doing that comparison?

Comment: @P. Kopacki Your comparison seems fine. usually that way the Django authentication works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a query like this?

`MyTable.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)`

This only returns the objects related to the current user.

Answer (score -1):

There are few ways you can try

verify user permissions in your own views using the has_perm method provided in the user model.

```
if user.has_perm('foo.add_bar'):
    return HttpResponse("You are authorized to add content!")
else:
    return HttpResponse("Permission to add denied")
```

verify in your templates using the perms variable that is automatically added to the template context.

```
{% if perms.app_label.can_do_something %}
    This content will be shown users with can_do_something permission.
{% endif %}
This content will be shown to all users.
```

You can also create your own permissions to the models

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_content', 'View content'),
        )
```

have a look at this [link](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2016/controlling-access-a-django-permission-apps-comparison/) it will give you an idea.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.